# convert mysql date and time to user friendly format?

Tags: php, mysql, date

i'm wanting to display a user friendly date format, so i am changing the mysql time stamp to keep it simpler for users. I've already got the code which echo's my desired date format and it works fine on other pages of my site. but i'm having trouble getting the date format to display in amongst a section of my code.

Here's the piece of code i'm using to convert mysql date to a user friendly format:

```
<?php 

    $datesent1 = $sentbox['date_sent']; 

    echo date('D M jS, Y', strtotime($datesent1));?>
```

And this is my code i am trying to incorporate it into:

```
<div class="message-date">
<?php echo "Conversation Dated:&nbsp;&nbsp;{$message['date_sent']}"; ?></div>
```

I should probably add that i am echoing $message['date_sent'] to retrieve the date a message was sent to the user in a table.

can anyone tell me how this is suppose to be done. Thanks, i'm new to php and mysql so sorry if it's a bit of a daft question.

Comment: Why are you echoing $message['date_sent']} ? Echo the date????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either save the pretty date in a variable and print it with the message or just do it where you print it like so

```
<?php echo "Conversation Dated:&nbsp;&nbsp;{".date('D M jS, Y', strtotime($message['date_sent']))."}"; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're so close....

...just assign the return value from `date()` to a variable and echo that out:

```
<?php 

    $datesent1 = $sentbox['date_sent']; 

    $pretty_date = date('D M jS, Y', strtotime($datesent1));?>

<div class="message-date">
<?php echo "Conversation Dated:&nbsp;&nbsp;{$pretty_date}"; ?></div>
```

Comment: Make sure `$sentbox['date_sent']` has a valid year in its format

Answer (score 1):

you can directly convert the mysql date to user friendly format by the sql query itslef, so that you can avoid the date related manipulation functions in PHP.

> ```
>   SELECT CONCAT(DAY(tbl_name.date_field),' ',
>   MONTHNAME(tbl_name.date_field),' ',
>   YEAR(tbl_name.date_field)) as 'datelabel' FROM tbl_name
> ```

The result datelabel will a date value looks like **"21 May 2014"**